# How to create field with formula using CAML XML

Tags: caml-query

Suppose I need a DateTime field that shows the current date + 30 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for creating a field with formula using Caml xml

```
<Field ID="{guid}" Name="MyDateTime" DisplayName="ExpiredDate" Type="DateTime" Format="DateOnly"> <DefaultFormula>=Today+30</DefaultFormula>
```

Reference:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/choroshin/archive/2011/12/26/creating-content-type-field-with-formula.aspx